# How to find out if you already have a pokemon and transfer out weaker one

Tags: pokemon-go

I know there's a limit to the number of pokemon you can store, and that you have to transfer them to the professor to get more room. My strategy is to keep one or two that are the highest level and transfer the rest out. Of course I need to keep catching pokemon even if I already have them, for the stardust.

My question is, is there a way to sort pokemon (for example in alphabetical order) or search by name? It's really hard if I catch an Ekans and I think I have another and search a bunch to find it to only realize my old one has the higher level. Let me know if the question doesn't make sense and I will refine.

Answer (score 8):

Yes. The bottom right corner of the Pokemon screen has a button that indicates how your Pokemon are currently sorted. There are name and number filters which would solve your problem.

Additionally, there is a CP filter that sorts your Pokemon from strongest to weakest, which helps when fighting gyms or finding a Pokemon to put into an open spot in a gym!

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the sorting option as was just explained, you can just keep in mind the specific pokemon's CP that you already have, assuming it is stronger and as an alternative you can transfer the weaker pokemon as you catch them 
to keep your party from cramming up because even with the filter it can be a pain going down the line transferring the same pokemon.

Answer (score 0):

To find out if you have a duplicate, simply click the icon in the lower right and change to sort by #. Sorting by recent can be a great way to see what you caught recently (like if an egg hatched but the game crashed before you could see what it was).

As far as deciding which is weaker, with the recent update, you can get your Pokemon appraised by your Gym Leader. They have a indepth breakdown [here](http://pokemongo.gamepress.gg/pokemon-appraisal).

However if you appraise a pokemon when you catch it, and want to candify the worst half of your pokemon look for these phrases (they signify that it's **IV**s are <50%):

- **Mystic** Overall, your Pokemon is not likely to make much headway in battle.
- **Valor** Overall, your Pokemon may not be great in battle, but I still like it!
- **Instinct** Overall, your Pokemon has room for improvement as far as battling goes.